# What is the mark next to the hallmark on this silver object?

Tags: silver, silver-hallmark

I got an object which is either made of silver or silver-plated (as far as I can see), and while studying the hallmark I noticed another mark close to the hallmark.

At first I thought it was nothing special or simply minor damage, but then I found the same mark on the other side and now I'm wondering whether it can tell me something about the object and if so, what?

The object is a French *carnet de bal* hallmarked with *P revolver Q* which according to [this site](http://www.silvercollection.it/frenchsilversmithsPDUE.html) is *Quitte and Prudent* - registered in 1882.

**EDIT** A *carnet de bal* is, freely translated in today's slang, a party notebook. A young *demoiselle* would take it with her to a ball and note with whom she danced which dance.

The *carnet* is around 5x3 cm big.

This is the object (front and backside), and I circled the positions of the marks. (click to enlarge)

[image]

These 2 pictures show the hallmarks and the mark in question:

[image] [image]

Comment: Could it possibly be the shape of the tip of the tongs the silversmith used to hold it while working?

Comment: @T.E.D., silversmiths wouldn't use tongs for something like that, and only the most sloppy silversmiths would leave marks like that on a finished piece.  The whole item looks like it was made by repousse, a process that would have no need for tongs: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repouss%C3%A9_and_chasing

Comment: @Joe is right, the object was done by the Repoussé-method. The back of the two plate witness that.

Comment: Very interesting question, and a beautiful... object?

Comment: What is the orientation of the mark in each spot?  Since it does appear, like you say, to come from the same thing, orientation may be important.  @Joe - While I agree it would be sloppy, the technique _does_ require annealing (reheating, basically), they might therefore use tongs.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Doesn't the photo of the object help with your question when you fully zoomed? (Click to enlarge and then click again, depending on your browser)

Comment: Yes, I'm curious what it is, or rather what kind of people used it. Some 19th century journalists?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My guess is that's a head of wild hog - French hallmark for 800/1000 silver fineness used for small objects from May 1838

[image]

Here is a [page about french hallmarking system on silvercollection.it](http://www.silvercollection.it/frenchhallmarks.html). Look for "Hallmarks from 10 May 1838".

Another [page from wineantique dedicated to silver standards](http://www.wineantique.com/DEFINITIONS/Silver%20Content%20Defined2.htm).

> French 800 was guaranteed by the Minerve 2. The Minerve surrounds were the same but now a 2 appeared just below her chin.  **Small 800 items were marked with a crab or warthog's head.**

**UPDATE:**
[Found the discussion of another carnet de bal](http://www.ascasonline.org/newsOTTOB42.html) with similar mark recognized as a silver standard hallmark:

> Marked on the front with the head of a wild boar (French hallmark for silver fineness of 800/1000, introduced for small silver articles on 10th May, 1838).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I actually found the link you found, but I didn't read carefully enough.